# How many "songs" are on the boom box in the Dog Shrine?

Tags: undertale

One of the rewards for donating to the Dog Shrine is a boom box. By interacting with it, you have the option to skip to the "next" song, and it is suggested that these songs may have some effect.

Are there a finite number of songs on the boom box, and if so, how many are there? What effect, if any, do these songs have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The boombox will reach the fastest speed after changing tracks 5 times.**

You can continue to skip tracks indefinitely, but it won't have any effect once the jukebox has reached its maximum speed.

Interestingly, if you visit the shrine during the True Pacifist ending, skipping tracks will [speed up the music for the entire world](https://www.reddit.com/r/Undertale/comments/6wvutn/dog_shrine_post_true_pacifist_ending/).